# Augmenting the Object class

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was fooling around with the idea of adding a method onto the Object class like so:

```
Object.prototype.is = function(operand) {
  return this === operand;
};

10.is(10); // returns false
```

I'm a little vexed by the outcome, can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: That code doesn't even run for me

Comment: The last line needs to be `10..is(10);`

Comment: Extending `Object.properties` is a bad idea. jQuery will hate you, for starters.

Comment: @lonesomeday You're right, why is that?

Comment: @knubie Because Javascript interprets a `.` after a number as a decimal point. With `..` the first `.` is treated as a decimal point, while the second is seen as the object member accessor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaScript, numeric primitives are not instances of `Number`. When the compiler sees `10.is` it wraps `10` in a `Number` object (since only objects can have properties). That object is not equal to the argument `10` because `===` suppresses automatic type conversion.

P.S. You need something like `(10).is(10)` for your code to be legal syntax.